# Укоротить код

Tags: jquery, javascript

Реализовал проверку на заполненность полей пользователем. Получился вот такой говнокод:

```
$('#button2').click(function (eventObject) {
    if ($('#add_phone').val() == '') {
        eventObject.preventDefault();
        $('#add_phone').addClass('border').effect('pulsate', 'slow');
    }
});

$('#button2').click(function (eventObject) {
    if ($('#add_street').val() == '') {
        eventObject.preventDefault();
        $('#add_street').addClass('border').effect('pulsate', 'slow');
    }
});

$('#button2').click(function (eventObject) {
    if ($('#add_home').val() == '') {
        eventObject.preventDefault();
        $('#add_home').addClass('border').effect('pulsate', 'slow');
    }
});

$('#button2').click(function (eventObject) {
    if ($('#add_title').val() == '') {
        eventObject.preventDefault();
        $('#add_title').addClass('border').effect('pulsate', 'slow');
    }
});
```

Как его можно уменьшить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как минимум использовать кэширование через var $addPhone =$('#add_phone'); и поместить все условные конструкции в один $('#button2').click();

Comment: все условия под одним if можно как-нибудь записать?

Comment: В голову приходит вариант: объединить в один jQuery-набор все нужные элементы и пройтись с помощью метода .each(), внутри которого проверять if($(this).val()=='') {$(this).addClass('border').effect('pulsate','slow');}

Answer (score 2):

```
var $button2 = $('#button2')
,   $check_variables_array = [$('#add_phone'), $('#add_street'), $('#add_home'), $('#add_title')];

$('#button2').click(function(eventObject) {

    for(var i=0; i < $check_variables_array.length; i++) {

        if($check_variables_array[i].val()=='') {   
            eventObject.preventDefault();
            $check_variables_array[i].addClass('border').effect('pulsate','slow');
        }   
    }
});
```

Comment: Данный код будет вызывать каждый элемент по очереди. Одно нажатие кнопки - один эффект. 
А необходимо, чтобы все проверялось вместе.